# How to iterate through a dynamic list in MyBatis and access the objects of the list

Tags: list, spring-boot, loops, foreach, mybatis-mapper

I would like to iterate through a list, get the object's name and match that name with the record in my database. Then fetch that record.

I tried to use the foreach tag in Mybatis but I only get an empty list in return. Please help me out and point out if I have made any mistakes.

For reference, I have attached my Service implementation, DAO, mapper & the list class I'm using.

**Service implementation**

```
String jsonStr = "[{\"name\":\"first \",\"value\":\"1 \"},{\"name\":\"second\",\"value\":\"2\"},{\"name\":\"third\",\"value\":\"3\"},{\"name\":\"fourth\",\"value\":\"4\"}]";

List<PaymentCommon.CampaignsRsp> list = null;
        try { // creating a list from the json String
            list = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<List<PaymentCommon.CampaignsRsp>>(){});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

if(JudgeUtils.isNotEmpty(rsp.getCampaigns())) {
            listRsp = cmmClmWhitelistingDao.getCampaigns(list); // calling the method
        }
        else System.out.println("LIST IS EMPTY");
```

**DAO**

```
package com.hisun.lemon.cmm.dao;

import com.hisun.lemon.cio.dto.common.PaymentCommon;
import com.hisun.lemon.cmm.entity.CmmClmCampaignDO;
import com.hisun.lemon.framework.dao.BaseDao;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface ICmmClmWhitelistingDao extends BaseDao {
    List<CmmClmCampaignDO> getCampaigns(List<PaymentCommon.CampaignsRsp> campaignList);
}
```

**Mapper**

```
<select id="getCampaigns" resultMap="BaseResultMap" >
    SELECT campaign.campaign_id, campaign.campaign_name,
    FROM clm_campaign campaign
    WHERE campaign.campaign_name IN
    <foreach item="id" collection="list" open="[{" separator="},{" close="}]" >
        #{id.name}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

**PaymentCommon.class**

```
 @Json
    public static class CampaignsRsp {
        @Item
        private String name;
        @Item
        private String value;

        public CampaignsRsp() {
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I am now getting the names from the List<PaymentCommon.CampaignsRSp> and making a simple List of those names. Then, I'm passing that list to the mapper, making it simple to iterate the list.
Plus, I was missing the @Param annotation in my DAO, so I added that.

This approach gets me the data I want from my DB.